# Updating multiple column & row sizes with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to adjust columns B to AF in excel. This is what I've tried so far:

Attempt 1:

```
worksheet.column_dimensions["B:AF"].width=35
```

Attempt 2:

```
worksheet.column_dimension["B":"AF"].width=35
```

In attempt 3 I tried to use a for loop but I get the error expected class str. Not sure how to correct this

```
col_range = worksheet["B:AF"]
for col in col_range:
        worksheet.column_dimensions[col].width=35
```

Comment: Use the `.group()` method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? (really new to python)

Comment: I tried col_range = worksheet["B:AF"] for col in col_range:      worksheet.column_dimensions[col].width=35 but this also didn't work